# Breakout game using GLUT library - Improvements

Tags: c, animation, opengl, glut, freeglut

This is a simple breakout game which is made using glut and codeblocks. The game currently works frame by frame with keyboard press(b and n), my question is how can I improve this game so that the ball is constantly moving at a fixed speed and give the player a chance to catch it with the rectangle?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<math.h>
#define pi 3.142857

// Global Declaration
// c and d tracks the number of time 'b' and 'n' pressed respectively
// left and right indicates leftmost and rightmost index of movable rectangle
int c = 0, d = 0, left = 0, right = 0;
int m = 0, j = 1, flag1 = 0, l = 1, flag2 = 0, n = 0, score = 0, count = 1;

// Initialization function
void myInit (void)
{
    // Reset background color with white (since all three argument is 1.0)
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    // Set picture color to red (in RGB model)
    // as only argument corresponding to R (Red) is 1.0 and rest are 0.0
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Set width of point to one unit
    glPointSize(1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Set window size in X- and Y- direction
    gluOrtho2D(-620.0, 620.0, -340.0, 340.0);
}

// keyboard function : it gets active when button pressed
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    left = -200 + 200 * (d - c);
    right = 200 + 200 * (d - c);

    // if leftmost index of window is hit
    // then rectangle will not move to left on furthure pressing of b
    // only it will move to right on pressing n
    if (left == -600)
    {
        // '110' -> Ascii value of 'n'
        // so d is incremented when n is pressed
        if (key == 110)
            d++;
    }
    // if rightmost index of window is hit
    // then rectangle will not move to right on furthure pressing of n
    // only it will move to left on pressing b
    else if (right == 600)
    {
        // '98' -> Ascii value of 'b'
        // so c is incremented when b is pressed
        if (key == 98)
            c++;
    }
    // when rectangle is in middle, then it will move into both
    // direction depending upon pressed key
    else
    {
        if (key == 98)
            c++;
        if (key == 110)
            d++;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    // x and y keeps point on circumference of circle
    int x, y, k;
    // outer 'for loop' is to for making motion in ball
    for (k = 0; k <= 400; k += 5)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        // i keeps track of angle
        float i = 0;
        // change in m denotes motion in vertical direction and
        // change in n denotes motion in horizontal direction
        m = m + 6;
        n = n + 4;
        // drawing of circle centre at (0, 12) iterated up to 2*pi, i.e., 360 degree
        while (i <= 2 * pi)
        {
            y = 12 + 20 * cos(i);
            x = 20 * sin(i);
            i = i + 0.1;
            // flag1 is 0 to show motion in upward direction and is 1 for downward direction
            if (m == 288 && flag1 == 0)
            {
                j = -1;
                m = -288;
                flag1 = 1;
                score++;
            }
            if (m == 288 && flag1 == 1)
            {
                j = 1;
                m = -288;
                flag1 = 0;
            }
            // flag2 is 0 to show motion in rightward direction and is 1 for leftward direction
            if (n == 580 && flag2 == 0)
            {
                l = -1;
                n = -580;
                flag2 = 1;
            }
            if (n == 580 && flag2 == 1)
            {
                l = 1;
                n = -580;
                flag2 = 0;
            }
            // equation for desired motion of ball
            glVertex2i((x - l * n), (y - j * m));
        }
        glEnd();

        // these four points draws outer rectangle which determines window
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
            glVertex2i(-600, -320);
            glVertex2i(-600, 320);
            glVertex2i(600, 320);
            glVertex2i(600, -320);
        glEnd();

        // these four points draws smaller rectangle which is for catching ball
                glColor3f(0,0,0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        left = -200 + 200 * (d - c);
        right = 200 + 200 * (d - c);
            glVertex2i(left, -315);
            glVertex2i(left, -295);
            glVertex2i(right, -295);
            glVertex2i(right, -315);
        glEnd();

        // following condition checks if falling ball is catched on rectangle or not
        if ((j * m) == 276)
        {
            if ((left > ((-1 * l * n) + 20)) || (right < (-1 * l * n) - 20))
            {
                printf("Game Over !!!\nYour Score is :\t%d\n", score);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
}


// Driver Program
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    // Declares window size
    glutInitWindowSize(1100, 600);

    // Declares window position which is (0, 0)
    // means lower left corner will indicate position (0, 0)
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);

    // Name to window
    glutCreateWindow("Game");

    // keyboard function
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    // Call to myInit()
    myInit();
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Your question is not a good fit for this website.  Spend some more time describing the issue, and remove all unnecessary code.  On the surface, it sounds like all you need to do is store the position and velocity (or just direction) of the ball, and update that in your game loop.  I suggest you also use more descriptive variable names, and avoid hard-coding ASCII values like `key == 98` instead of `key == 'b'`.

Comment: I'd start with removing that `for (k = 0; k <= 400; k += 5)` -- that's really not how you do animations with GLUT.